# Display meta data from a custom field within plugin Category Grid View Gallery

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, post-meta, gallery

I am using [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-grid-view-gallery/) plugin, which creates a gallery of posts, fetching a thumbnail and the titles of the posts displayed in it.

I have enabled [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), and have created (and filled in values) a field for the posts I want displayed in the gallery. I know that I have to put `<?php the_meta(); ?>` within the loop for the meta data from the fields to show, which I have done and it works.

Now what I am wondering is: Can I somehow show the meta data from the fields within the plugin? Specifically, beneath (or instead of) the post title which the plugin already fetches and displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the name of the custom field in the shortcode:

```
[cgview title="fieldname"]
```

Not tested; I just took a look at the source code (and now my eyes hurt).